# When does an odd polynomial over a field have a zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $f(x)$ be an odd degree, non constant polynomial over an infinite field $K$. Under what conditions is $f(x)$ guaranteed to have a zero in $K$.
For example, we know it will have a zero, if $K$ is complete. (under some assumptions which allow the mean value theorem to hold). We also trivially know $f(x)$ will have a zero if $K$ is algebraically closed.

However, there are some examples where this holds without completeness or algebraic closure. Such as if $K=\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\cap\mathbb{R}$. Is there a nice criterion we can see in general for when $f(x)$ will have a zero.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of [Real-closed field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field)? This might not be specifically what you're looking for, but it's a starting point.

Comment: The equivalent formulations for a real closed field are quite helpful, although I guess now I just need to find a proof of them being equivalent. Thank you

Comment: Very welcome! It may be worth noting that that doesn't necessarily solve your problem, because the characterizations of real-closed fields all seem to start with an ordered field, which may not cover your situation, depending; e.g., I don't know if the condition holds for any finite $F_{p^n}$.

Comment: It should, because the real problem I was having, was to try to prove that odd polynomials over the reals have a zero, without using the mean value theorem (so without using completeness, and without using FTA). Hopefully seeing the proof of those equivalencies will help.